# Data conversion failed while converting Time from CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

[image: Csv Image]

Problem:in mentioned Screenshoot data cannot able to convert into Time format column in SQL , this data is coming from csv file and executed by SSIS package  only these column data from csv as string cannot loaded into database table

Error1:[OLE DB Destination [76]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Recurring Start Time] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: did you try CONVERT( TIME, '10:00:22' ) in your query? write your insert query in question if you can.

Comment: @hosseinzakizadeh not explicitly , but in connection manager on advanced tab changed this column type as 'DT_DBTIME' but still no use, NULL are coming in place of dates in DB  when i ignore failure

Comment: Try replacing your SQL Server destination with an OLE DB destination.  SQL Server destinations are type-specific and do not allow casts, implicit or not (as far as I know).

Comment: I wrote my comment as the answer. please check my answer to be clear what is the solution.

Comment: Load the data into a staging table where all he values are strings.  Then do the conversion in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your SQL Server destination with an OLE DB destination. SQL Server destinations are type-specific and do not allow casts, implicit or not (as far as I know).